# URL external data with jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{



var response = $.ajax({ type: "GET",   
                          url : "http://www.google.com",   
                        async : false,
                      success : function(resp) {
                                    alert(resp);
                                }
               });



});
```

no output....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to break the "[ajax same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)".

That means, you cannot access a foreign domain with an Ajax request.
"Workarounds" are to use [JSONP](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/), [HTML5](http://ajaxian.com/archives/cross-window-messaging-with-html-5-postmessage) or [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/). All of those must be supported serverside.

The most common thing to solve this issue is, to use your webserver as a proxy.
Let your server make the request and send the results back to your website.

Comment: Thank you!. You have any idea about facebook displaying URL title and Meta description

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but can try something like

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

or have a look here http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
 body{ font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial; }
 </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<b>Footer navigation:</b>
<ol id="new-nav"></ol>

<script>
  $("#new-nav").load("/ #jq-footerNavigation li");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

If you know PHP you can try .. http://www.wait-till-i.com/2010/01/10/loading-external-content-with-ajax-using-jquery-and-yql/

Comment: while giving local URL (eg: abc.html) it is working fine, But URL(http://abc.com) no output

Comment: Ok got it.. perhaps @jAndy's answer help you.